# How to use geth monitor to view txpool metrics?

Tags: go-ethereum, monitoring

I would like to view Ethereum txpool. From geth command line page it seems like I can use `geth monitor` to get a view of the txpool metic. But there aren't many document on how to use the tool.

Does anyone know a good example of using `geth monitor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the [geth documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring) describes pretty well how to use the tool geth monitor.
Essentially, to do so you need to start a geth instance with both the `--metrics` flag and the support for the `debug` api.

An example for a local ethereum network:

```
geth \
    --rpc \
    --rpcport 8545 \
    --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 \
    --rpccorsdomain 127.0.0.1 \
    --rpcapi "eth,web3,miner,net,admin,personal,debug" \
    --metrics \
    --bootnodes <your-bootnodes>
```

So now you can check that it shows correctly the metrics:

```
geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545 --exec "debug.metrics(false)"
```

And in particular for the txpool metrics:

```
 geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545 --exec "debug.metrics(false).txpool"
```

Now you can try to follow the documentation to show the real time graphics for the txpool:

```
 geth monitor --attach=http://127.0.0.1:8545 txpool
```

**N.B.**
As reported in the question [Geth monitor graphics character encoding](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49530/geth-monitor-graphics-character-encoding), you may have some problems with the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any success with this?
I believe the node you wish to gather statistics from has to have --metrics set at startup?  I have got to the stage of having graph axis displayed, but no data...

Comment: Can I ask you what type of character encoding do you use to show the axes?  Or what type of shell?

Comment: Briomkez << Huge respect, got it working..!  Happy Unicorn :)

Comment: SSH to Ubuntu 16.10, usual vanilla BASH shell.

My command: ../bin/geth_1811 monitor --attach=http://192.168.1.100:8547 txpool
This gives ten "windows" all monitoring various aspects: pending, queued etc.

Make sure you run first "collecting" instance of Geth with the apis:eth,web3,miner,net,admin,personal,debug < what I messed up on... 

Hth

Comment: BTW:
Some metrics to play with:

system/disk/readcount/MeanRate
system/disk/readcount/Overall
system/disk/readdata/Overall
system/disk/writecount/Overall
system/memory/allocs/Overall
system/memory/frees/Overall
system/memory/inuse/Overall