# Geth monitor graphics character encoding

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have a local network in which I start each node with both the `--metrics` flag and the `debug` api enabled. So I can attach a console and retrieve the metrics by running, for instance

```
geth attach --exec "debug.metrics(false)" http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

and it works like a charm.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring) it is stated, that one can use geth monitor to have a real-time view of the metrics graphics. Therefore I tried to follow the documentation with this command:

```
geth monitor --attach http://127.0.0.1:8545 "system/memory/allocs"
```

But I get unfortunately incomprehensible results as proved by this screenshot:
[image]

I think that this is probably due to the encoding used by the graphics. Therefore I tried with the majority of the encoding provided by my shell (KDE Konsole) but the result, remain always incomprehensible. (The Picture show the result with UTF-8).

Do one of you had the same problem, which is the right encoding to show the graph as in the documentation?

**Additional Info**:

`geth version` 1.8.8-stable

`go version`  go1.10.2

`os` Linux 4.9

`shell` kde-konsole

**UPDATE** I did try with Ubuntu and it works fine. Is it possible that I miss some packages?